# System.ExecutionEngineException при попытке маршализации структуры

Tags: c#, struct

Есть программа на C#, предназначенная для конфигурирования устройства на микроконтроллере через USB порт.
Для того, чтобы корректно передавать данные микроконтроллеру (Си, жесткие требования к ресурсам), я храню их в виде структуры фиксированного размера:

```
SystemPack InternalSystemPacket = new SystemPack(); // Текущий пакет данных со стороны ПК        

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct SystemPack
{
    public ushort PackLength; // Перед отправкой пакета контроллеру сюда надо записать общую длину пакета

    // Вкладка "Информация"
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = DEVICENAMELENGTH)]
    public byte[] DeviceName;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = STRINGLENGTH)]
    public byte[] DeviceVersion;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = REQUESTLENGTH)]
    public byte[] DeviceIMEI;
```

и т. д.

Перед передачей данных контроллеру по USB (а также для записи данных на диск) я подвергаю структуру маршализации для превращения ее в массив данных:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(InternalSystemPacket)];

GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(InternalSystemPacket, h.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false);
h.Free();
```

Все работало нормально. Но при изменении структуры (я удлинил один ее член):

```
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = REQUESTLENGTH + 1)]
 public byte[] DeviceIMEI;
```

при попытке маршализации вылетает `System.ExecutionEngineException`:

[image: Ошибка при маршализации]

Comment: Ну так что вы хотите? Вы обещали, что размер данных будет `REQUESTLENGTH + 1`, и не выполнили ваше обещание: нативная функция наверное использует сигнатуру с более короткой строкой? Вот вам и исключение.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что массив, записанный в поле `DeviceIMEI`, остался старого размера.

PS Но зачем все так сложно? Зачем вам вообще маршаллинг структуры, если все что нужно - это сформировать правильный массив?

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);
writer.Write((ushort)0); // Место для длины пакета

Debug.Assert(packet.DeviceName.Length == DEVICENAMELENGTH);
writer.Write(packet.DeviceName);

Debug.Assert(packet.DeviceVersion.Length == STRINGLENGTH);
writer.Write(packet.DeviceVersion);

Debug.Assert(packet.DeviceIMEI.Length == REQUESTLENGTH);
writer.Write(packet.DeviceIMEI);

var length = writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
writer.Write((ushort)length);
writer.Flush();

var packetData = ms.ToArray();
```

Кстати, `BinaryWriter` умеет и строки напрямую записывать, если ему в конструктор кодировку передать. Только с проверкой длины придется что-нибудь думать, вроде такого:

```
// Код ниже напрашивается на вынесение в отдельную подпрограмму
var i = writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
writer.Write(packet.DeviceName); // Допустим, это - строка
i = writer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current) - i;
if (i > DEVICENAMELENGTH)
  throw new ArgumentException("too long", "packet.DeviceName");
else for (; i < DEVICENAMELENGTH; i++)
  writer.Write((byte)0);
```

Comment: Да, действительно, при предварительном переписывании свойств визуальных компонентов в структуру осталось  InternalSystemPacket.DeviceIMEI = StringToASCIIArray(IMEI_Label.Text, STRINGLENGTH); Если заменить на STRINGLENGTH + 1, то все в ажуре.